# OnTriggerEnter2D or OnCollisionEnter2D not getting called

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I checked the other answers for this but mine didn't get fixed
Here's the code

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyCollectibles : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hallo");
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Trigger");
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collsion");
        // if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Collectible"))
        // {
        //     Debug.Log("Apple");
        //     Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        // }
    }
}
```

And screenshots:

[image: Destroyer]
[image: collectible]

Comment: Missing one rigidbody2d on one object

Comment: Ohhh So i need a rigid body

Comment: OnTriggerEnter is called if your BoxCollider2D (the one which something should enter) is marked as trigger. And as Zibelas said, you are missing a RigidBody2D on one object (the one that is entering). See the note in the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html or
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: That looks like it would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnTriggerEnter() is called if your `BoxCollider2D` (the one which something should enter) is marked as `trigger`. And as Zibelas said, you are missing a `RigidBody2D` on one object (the one that is entering).

A quote from the Unity documentation on [MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html):

> **Note:** Trigger events are only sent if one of the Colliders also has a Rigidbody2D attached. Trigger events are sent to disabled MonoBehaviours, to allow enabling Behaviours in response to collisions.